# how to make vertical carousal using twitter-bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I want to make vertical carousel. I'm using knockout for binding but i am unable to do so. 
when i view the file nothing in the data is getting displayed. Only thing that is getting displayed is next prev buttons.
how it can be done?

html is as below:

```
<div class="middleLeftDiv">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide vertical" data-bind="foreach: AssociationTypes">
        <div class="carousel-inner clickable" data-bind="attr: { id: ObjectAssociationType }" onclick="onSelectAssociation(this)">
            <div class="active item">
                <span class="veticaltextname1" data-bind="text: ObjectAssociationType"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Carousel nav -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS file i'm binding with Knockout:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/member/GetMemberItems',
    data: ko.toJSON({ typeOfMedia: typeOfMedia }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {
        if (!hasError(response)) {
            self.Association(response);
        }
    }
});
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

The CSS:

```
.vertical .carousel-inner {
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
     -moz-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
      -ms-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
       -o-transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
          transition: 0.6s ease-in-out top;
}

.carousel.vertical .active {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .next {
  top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .prev {
  top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .prev.right {
  top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.left {
  top: -100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .active.right {
  top: 100%;
}

.carousel.vertical .item {
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to grasp, you're missing essential bits to help us [reproduce](http://sscce.org) the issue, but also adding a lot of irrelevant code (the ajax bit, loads of css). Please update your question, help us help you.

Comment: @Jeroen : actually the ajax is where i ll get the data to bind using knockout...i gave all the css that i tried so far...its all the code that i tried so far for this issue...as in one of my previous question some body told me to give all the code thats been tried so far before posting...thanks

Comment: Yes, of course you should provide all the *relevant* code, but not necessarily *all* code, this makes it harder for us to help you. In any case, the fact that there's still code *missing* is the biggest problem in helping you. See for example [this jsfiddle with all of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/NENtd/): we can't answer the question using only that, there's just too much missing. Please see [the link I gave earlier](http://sscce.org) for help on creating a good repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be help you.
Not responsive but It can solve your issue regarding vertical carousal

[Github](http://github.com/tutorialdrive/-Bootstrap-Vertical-Thumbnail-Carousel)